# PonyORM MappingError: Database object is not bound with a provider yet

Tags: python, orm, ponyorm, pony

Python 3.11, pony 0.7.17:
I run my PonyORM setup code in this __init __.py

```
from pony import orm

db = orm.Database()


def startup_database():
    db.bind(
        provider="postgres",
        user="...",
        password="...",
        host="localhost",
        database="...",
        port="5432",
    )
    orm.sql_debug(True)


def main():
    startup_database()  # If you have another methods, THIS LINE SHOULD BE THE LAST ONE


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then a User Entity is defined in another user.py module like this:

```
from pony.orm import *


db = Database()


class User(db.Entity):
    firstname = Required(str)
    lastname = Required(str)
    email = Required(str)
    ...
    

db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

However, running that code gives me this error:
pony.orm.core.MappingError: Database object is not bound with a provider yet

initiated by the user.py > db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
but binding already happened in the __init __.py > startup_database() function - right?